# UITableView floating header without inheriting from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, floating

I have two viewControllers, one inheriting from UIViewController and another one inheriting from UITableViewController. When I try to do

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
}
```

It runs in UITableViewController class but when i try to do it on the UIViewController class code sense doesn't show it up and it doesn't even run. Anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ViewController Class, add the following lines

```
@interface YourClass : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>{
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *yourTableView
}
```

Now in your viewDidLoad, add the following lines

```
_yourTableView.delegate = self;
_yourTableView.dataSource = self;
```

This will make calls to all delegates & dataSource methods of UITableView in your ViewController.